# How can I force the rediscovery of PulseAudio virtual sound devices?

Tags: networking, sound, pulseaudio, avahi

I'm using the PulseAudio feature of network sound devices (not Multicast/RTP) to play sound from my netbook on the audio equipment connected to the HTPC when at home. This creates a virtual sound device that I can then use instead of the physical built-in one. Most of the time this works just fine. Sometimes however, the virtual sound device just doesn't appear. Disconnecting from and reconnecting to the network helps sometimes but not always and it's annoying and potentially bad for existing TCP connections.

So my question basically is: Is there some way to tell PulseAudio "Hey, just look again if you *really* can't find a network sound device."?

---

**Edit:** Unloading and reloading the `module-zeroconf-discover` with `pacmd` does not help either and it doesn't *appear* to be an avahi problem per se since `avahi-browse -t --all | grep PulseAudio` shows lots of right-looking stuff, even when the devices aren't listed in pavucontrol or `pacmd list-sinks`.

---

**Edit 2:** I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on both boxes for all the difference it might make.

Comment: If you're missing any information to provide helpful comments or even an answer, please tell me so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `sudo service avahi-daemon restart` does the trick, even though `avahi-browse` sees the devices before that avahi restart. Thanks to Takkat for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9):

1. On the "Sink" PC (On whose speaker you wanna play the sound) open the PulseAudio command shell by going into Terminal and issuing the following command.

   `$ pacmd`

   You will see a Python-like shell with the following welcome message.
   `Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
   >>>`
2. List the devices that can play the sound on the PC by the command in the PulseAudio shell. 
   `>>> list-sinks`

    Now you'll see a detailed list of all the sound sinks.
3. Just note down the complete **name** of the sink of your choice. It would appear as an attribute of the sound card. For example in my case it is:
   `1 sink(s) available.
   index: 0 
   name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>` 
   ...

The string of my interest is just "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"

4. Now Go onto the Source PC (i.e. origin of the audio multimedia streams), open up the terminal and issue the following command
   `$ pactl load-module module-tunnel-sink "server=192.168.1.105 sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo sink_name=home_theater"`
   Here 192.168.1.105 is the IP address of the sink PC, "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" is the string you just copied from sink's terminal and "home_theater" is just a fancy name to call this virtual sound output device on your computer.
5. Finally select this virtual sound device by : 
   `$ pacmd set-default-sink home_theater` 

   **Wallah !!**

Comment: Worked for me - works with the new tunnel sink module too and with just the sink's host IP address without needing to specify the exact sink (I use only one on this Raspberry Pi connected to my stereo, so no need for that) : 'pactl load-module module-tunnel-sink-new  server=[2001:470:ca90:4:ba27:ebff:fee2:ada9]' - thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This answer is untested so it might not work, but it may lead you to the right direction.

I can confirm unresolved [issues with an Avahi service](https://askubuntu.com/a/51127/3940) that sometimes is unable to connect to a PulseAudio server. We may succeed reconnecting by either restarting the network, or the pulseaudio server but alas this does not always work.

To overcome this issue we may try to establish a network audio stream using the native TCP protocol to stream directly to the IP rather than using an Avahi name resolution.

To do so we can tunnel a remote sink by loading the [module-tunnel-sink](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-tunnel) on the receiver side. On the sender we have to enable the native TCP protocol by loading [module-native-protocol-tcp](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-native-protocol-.7Bunix.2Ctcp.7D).

See also this question for terminology and how to define the `PULSE_SERVER` variable:

[How to automatically set PulseAudio default sink to remote server at boot - Ubuntu 9.04](https://superuser.com/q/210617)

It is a rather old question for Ubuntu 9.04 but to my knwoledge terminology and procedures have not changed much since then.

Please also follow the [PulseAudio Wiki on network connections](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network).

Comment: Thanks for the one link. The solution there actually works in my case, too: `sudo service avahi-daemon restart` I didn't expect that because `avahi-browse` sees the devices even before the restart but I guess the restart triggers the callback to be called again which is all that is needed.

Comment: @Christian: good it helped. I have given up on Avahi for the time being.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your proposition though. Can I use the DNS name resolution or do I have to know the IP? I'd rather not use fixed IPs although you might say in case of the HTPC this is an ok thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand why. I just wrote my own reply though because for people who stumble on this question because they have the same problem it seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `pulseaudio -k`, which kills the pulseaudio service (it seems to start up again automatically). This has brought things back for me before.

The other thing which sometimes helps is unticking and then reticking the boxes in `Pulseaudio Preferences` (a.k.a. `paprefs`). Checkboxes are `Make discoverable PulseAudio network sound devices available locally` in `Network Access`, and `Enable network access to local sound devices` in `Network Server`. Obviously this probably only works for the one you're using.